# Extra padding/margin added in Firefox when float:left

Tags: css

Can anyone help me to understand this please?

You can see the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zhsnj/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="rt-block">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="itemContainer">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
            </div>
            <div class="clr"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="k2Pagination">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rt-block {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    position:relative;
}

.itemContainer {float:left;}

.k2Pagination {
    margin: 24px 0 4px;
}

.clr {
    border: medium none;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

In Firefox, there is a gap between the "itemContainer" and the surrounding "rt-block". Other browsers don't have this.

It is fixed by two things: removing the float:left on itemContainer, and also by removing the margin on k2 pagination. I'd prefer not to do either of these things if possible.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have this gap in every browser? Which makes sense since there is a padding of 15px. If you're talking about the gap below it also makes sense since there is k2Pagination with a margin. Maybe you should add borders and make a screenshot of which gap you mean. This http://jsfiddle.net/zhsnj/4/ looks exactly the same on chrome, ff and ie9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is the display as I see it in Firefox:

[image]

I think you have one too many `<div>`. When viewing on firefox the extra padding is added on the first `<div>` after `<div class="rt-block">`. My guess is that it produces a line break that causes the float to float under the line, it seems to be confirmed by the fact that adding `line-height: 0` to this div fixes the problem.

You can remove the extra `<div>`:

```
<div class="rt-block">
    <div>
        <div class="itemContainer">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
        </div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="k2Pagination">
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4UWv/)

Or you can set the line height to 0 for the first div:

```
.rt-block > div {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SkLC/1/)

Or better, make it inline-block:

```
.rt-block > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SkLC/2/)

Comment: @Layne That's weird, I have an extra 23px in Firefox.

Comment: Yeah, nvm. my borders somehow messed around with the firefox behavior and reduced it to a 3-5px difference.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do either of those in the actual project, because it is a Joomla template and the extra divs actually have styling and are needed. (I removed the styling to simplify things for teh jsfiddle example).
Are there any other possible solutions?  If not, I will just have to remove the "k2Pagination" div, which I don't really need.

Comment: @alexrees Can't you do the 3rd solution? `.rt-block > div {display: inline-block;}` ? You don't need to change the HTML, just add this CSS rule.

Comment: I didn't see the 3rd one.  Yes that works!  I had to also give it width:100% because it was collapsing the divs inside it.  It looks like it works with no negative side effects!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is the reason for that extra spacing in Firefox but you can give padding instead of margin.

```
.k2Pagination {
padding: 24px 0 4px;}
```

This is simple and it might work.

Comment: That works, thanks.  Strange that the problem only appears with margin and no padding.  The inline-block fix above is even better though I think